# LLVM cmake install cannot find DIA SDK

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, clang, llvm, libclang

I'm trying to build the LLVM install with cmake but it is giving me an error about the LLVM_ENABLE_DIA_SDK. I managed to build LLVM before without PDB's but I am trying to get started with libclang so I need the PDB. Cmake gives me the following error:

> CMake Error at cmake/config-ix.cmake:482 (message):
>     DIA SDK not found.  If you have both VS 2012 and 2013 installed, you may
>     need to uninstall the former and re-install the latter afterwards.
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     CMakeLists.txt:575 (include)

I have VS 2014 installed (2015 with update 3) which does have a DIA folder. Could anyone tell me how to point it to the right DIA SDK location?

Comment: I just had to run cmake in a visual studio command prompt for this to work. I am using Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem today, and Kerry Seitz's answer does work.

Actually, the environment variable `VSINSTALLDIR` doesn't have to be set manually -- Instead, open the Developer Command Prompt for VS. It will execute a batch script and create the `VSINTALLDIR` properly. Run CMake within that prompt, then everything will be OK.

[image: Inspect the VSINSTALLDIR variable]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like LLVM's CMake files assume an environment variable called `VSINSTALLDIR`.

See: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/cmake/config-ix.cmake#L475

I'm not sure the *right* way to set this environment variable, but I manually created said environment variable for my user account and set it to the root of my Visual Studio install directory (e.g., `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\`). That fixed the issue for me.

Note: I included a trailing `\` in the variable, but I am not sure if it is necessary.

Comment: The trailing \ is indeed mandatory. For me, this worked: set VSINSTALLDIR=c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\. Also, must not use "" around the path. Any of these will cause `set(MSVC_DIA_SDK_DIR "$ENV{VSINSTALLDIR}DIA SDK")` in `config-ix.cmake` to fail.